# How to only display certain images in a folder into a Repeater in ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, image, repeater, itemdatabound

I have a Repeater that takes all my images in a folder and display it. But what code changes must I make to only allow lets say Image1.jpg and Image2.jpg to be displayed in my repeater. I don"t want the repeater to display ALL the images in my folder.

My Repeater

```
<asp:Repeater ID="repImages" runat="server" OnItemDataBound="repImages_ItemDataBound">
<HeaderTemplate><p></HeaderTemplate>
<ItemTemplate>
    <asp:HyperLink ID="hlWhat" runat="server" rel="imagebox-bw">
    <asp:Image ID="imgTheImage" runat="server" />
    </asp:HyperLink>
</ItemTemplate>
<FooterTemplate></p></FooterTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>
```

My Code behind - PAGE LOAD

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!IsPostBack)
        {
            string sBasePath = System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Request.ServerVariables["APPL_PHYSICAL_PATH"];
            if ( sBasePath.EndsWith("\\"))
                sBasePath = sBasePath.Substring(0,sBasePath.Length-1);

            sBasePath = sBasePath + "\\" + "pics";

            System.Collections.Generic.List<string> oList = new System.Collections.Generic.List<string>();
            foreach (string s in System.IO.Directory.GetFiles(sBasePath, "*.*"))
            {
                //We could do some filtering for example only adding .jpg or something
                oList.Add( System.IO.Path.GetFileName( s ));

            }
            repImages.DataSource = oList;
            repImages.DataBind();
        }

    }
```

My Code behind - Repeater's ItemDataBound event code

```
protected void repImages_ItemDataBound(object sender, RepeaterItemEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.AlternatingItem ||
            e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.Item)
        {
            string sFile = e.Item.DataItem as string;

            //Create the thumblink
            HyperLink hlWhat = e.Item.FindControl("hlWhat") as HyperLink;
            hlWhat.NavigateUrl = ResolveUrl("~/pics/" + sFile  );
            hlWhat.ToolTip = System.IO.Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(sFile);
            hlWhat.Attributes["rel"] = "imagebox-bw";

            Image oImg = e.Item.FindControl("imgTheImage") as Image;
            oImg.ImageUrl = ResolveUrl("~/createthumb.ashx?gu=/pics/" + sFile + "&xmax=100&ymax=100" );


        }

    }
```

**ANSWER:**

My updated Page Load

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!IsPostBack)
        {
            string sBasePath = System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Request.ServerVariables["APPL_PHYSICAL_PATH"];
            if ( sBasePath.EndsWith("\\"))
                sBasePath = sBasePath.Substring(0,sBasePath.Length-1);

            sBasePath = sBasePath + "\\" + "pics";

            System.Collections.Generic.List<string> oList = new System.Collections.Generic.List<string>();

            string[] extensions = { "*.jpg", "*.png" };

            List<string> files = new List<string>(); 

            foreach (string filter in extensions) 
            {
                files.AddRange(System.IO.Directory.GetFiles(sBasePath, filter)); 
                oList.Add(System.IO.Path.GetFileName(filter));
            }


            repImages.DataSource = oList;
            repImages.DataBind();
        }
```

Comment: You seem to know that you want to filter the list, and where you need to do it - what exactly is your question?

Comment: Now under my EDIT section......its not returning any images

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What format are the image names that you want to display? If you know that you can construct a filter to use when listing the contents of the directory:

```
string[] files = Directory.GetFiles(folder, "*1.jpg");
```

Will list all the jpg files that end in "1"

EDIT:

Instead of having:

```
foreach (string s in System.IO.Directory.GetFiles(sBasePath, "*.*"))
{
    //We could do some filtering for example only adding .jpg or something
    oList.Add( System.IO.Path.GetFileName( s ));
}
```

You'd have:

```
string[] files = System.IO.Directory.GetFiles(sBasePath, "*.jpg")
foreach (string s in files)
{
    oList.Add( System.IO.Path.GetFileName( s ));
}
```

EDIT 2:

I've done a quick search and it looks like Get Files won't take multiple extensions, so you'll have to search for each type of extension separately:

```
string[] extensions = {"*.jpg" , "*.png" };

List<string> files = new List<string>();
foreach(string filter in extensions)
{
    files.AddRange(System.IO.Directory.GetFiles(path, filter));
}
foreach (string s in files)
{
    oList.Add( System.IO.Path.GetFileName( s ));
}
```

Comment: Where must i place that code. Or what must i replace? Sorry i am not that good with C#.

Comment: @Etienne - I'm not too hot on Regex, but there'll be a regular expression you can use to for that - I'll do a search and see if I can find it

Comment: Thanks for this ChrisF , but for some reason my Repeater is still returning all my Images in my Folder. Must i not change anything inside my ItemDataBound event?

Comment: Done, had to restart my PC, something was not working properly.  Now its not returning any images with your Edit 2 code.

Comment: Thanks! i got it, i had to add this oList.Add(System.IO.Path.GetFileName(filter)); in my loop

Comment: Only thing i have noticed is. When i use this.......string[] extensions = { "*.jpg" };...........it does not return any images at all. Any idea?

Comment: Does my latest revision make more sense? I can't see why only having one element in the array doesn't work. Have you tried stepping through on a debugger?

Comment: Got it thanks - tell me.....What code changes must i make to let my code look at a hyperlink for the image and not the "pics" folder? Any Idea? Example: http://www.erate.co.za/imgGrab.aspx?Id=99 ---- thats where the image is located and not in my "pics" folder.

Comment: This is where i posted the question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/728862/getting-image-from-hyperlink-and-not-from-folder-to-populate-my-repeater-control

Answer (score 2):

Easiest way to is load them all into a List<> and then use Linq to filter out the ones you want.

**VS2005**

```
public class GetFiles
{

    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        FileInfo[] files = 
            new DirectoryInfo(@"D:\downloads\_Installs").GetFiles();
        ArrayList exefiles = new ArrayList();

        foreach (FileInfo f in files)
        {
            if (f.Extension == ".exe") // or whatever matching you want to do.
            {
                exefiles.Add(f);
            }
        }

        foreach (FileInfo f in exefiles)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(f.FullName);
        }
        Console.ReadKey();
    }
}
```

**VS2008**

```
public class GetFiles
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        FileInfo[] files = 
            new DirectoryInfo(@"D:\downloads\_Installs").GetFiles();

        var exefiles = from FileInfo f in files 
                       where f.Extension == ".exe" 
                       select f;

        foreach (FileInfo f in exefiles)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(f.FullName);
        }

        Console.ReadKey();
    }
}
```

Comment: Cant use Linq because i am using VS 2005

Answer (score 0):

What you will need to do is filter out all the images you do not wish to display from your list before you bind it to your repeater control.