# Get filenames by URL Directory in WinService or WinForms application

Tags: c#, .net, windows-services, io

I have win service which must download all zip files by URL(for example http://download.geonames.org/export/dump/) but when i use `Directory.GetFiles` method or `DirectoryInfo di = new DirectoryInfo(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["GeoFullDataURLPath"])` i get error:

> URI formats are not supported..

How i can resolve this problem?

Comment: Is the URL matching a local path?

Comment: URL on remote server, it's is not local path...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The full source code for performing this task is:

```
string
    storeLocation = "C:\\dump",
    fileName = "",
    baseURL = "http://download.geonames.org/export/dump/";

WebClient r = new WebClient();            
string content = r.DownloadString(baseURL);
foreach (Match m in Regex.Matches(content, "<a href=\\\"[^\\.]+\\.zip\">"))
{
    fileName = Regex.Match(m.Value, "\\w+\\.zip").Value;
    r.DownloadFile(baseURL + fileName, Path.Combine(storeLocation, fileName));
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You have to make a WebRequest.  DirectoryInfo is for local drives and SMB shares only I believe.  This should do the trick : http://www.csharp-examples.net/download-files/

Comment: http://www.csharp-examples.net/download-files/ in this link - how to download files, but i need list of all files by url, not how download..

Comment: You will have to parse the HTML of the page that lists the files in order to ascertain the URL of each target.  Shai's answer has a link to something that might help.

Answer (score 2):

You can't use `Directory.GetFiles` on a URL.

Consider the following example:

```
 WebClient webClient = new WebClient();
 webClient.DownloadFile("http://download.geonames.org/export/dump/file.zip", "new-file.zip");
```

This will download the file *file.zip* from the URL above.

Directory listings over web is usually blocked for security reasons,

EDIT:
See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/771950/c-sharp-check-files-on-server-using-web-client)

Comment: @AlexeyZ. AFAIK there is no built in function with which you can do that,I guess its time to get your hands dirty (with the code of-course) :)