# load images from a folder

Tags: c#, asp.net-4.0

I want to load images from a folder located on my server eg. webimages and its located in my web root. How can i load these images without predefining paths in XML or database?

I mean, if i add some image in the webimages, my code should automatically load the images from this folder. All i need to tell the code is to point to that folder and it should return me all the images in that folder.

Comment: Already answered here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/724928/how-to-only-display-certain-images-in-a-folder-into-a-repeater-in-asp-net

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You use the MapPath Function to return the underlying folder:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpserverutility.mappath.aspx

And use the Directory class to get the contents of the Folder:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.directory(v=VS.100).aspx